# Is there a way to store form layout in order to generate form dynamically in django mvt?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm working on a pretty large Django project, which has over 60 different forms layout (can be more than this when needed). I pretty confuse that how can I build all such forms manually??. I've came up with an idea is that I'm gonna store form layout in database and with every new forms, I just need to config in database and then using crispy layout to dynamically generate those forms...
Do you guys have any better ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I worked on a form heavy project I used to rely on mixin.
Try to identify what are the comonly used type of field and create them in mixins.

If it's a lot of them then create some 'base' forms that incorporate certain set of fields.

Then you just have to compose the form you want from the diffrents mixins and bases and add anything specific to the new one you want to create.

Or you could create your own mapping structure for form and store the logic on how to build your form in a JsonField for exemple.
a json containing such thing as name, label, widgets, placeholder, (and whatever you need). It can be really simple or really complex if you have complicated structure...

Answer (score 1):

Crispy-forms has dynamic layouts which may help for this use case.

https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dynamic_layouts.html